# JavaScript promise .then() not executing

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

I'm trying to download a bunch of files, store a bit of data about each one, and then use that data to process them further. I'm later using `Promise.map(queue,(x)=>get_image(...x),{concurrency: 1}).all().then(   )` to process all of them together afterwards. But after one of my `.then()` calls, no further `.then()` calls seem to work: `'download processed'` is never printed, even though `'processing downloaded image'` is.  Could someone tell me what I'm missing?

```
var get_image = (page_string, row, col) => {
  var url = get_url(page_string,row,col)
  var path = 'results/'+page_string+'/'+page_string.match(/f\d\d\d\w/)[0]+'_r'+pad_int(row)+'_c'+pad_int(col)+'.jpg'
  y = download(url,path)
    .then(process_downloaded(path))
    .then((x) => {console.log('download processed'); return x})
  return y
}

var download = (url, dest) => {
  console.log('attempting download')
  console.log(url)
  var y = new Promise((res,err) => {
    request(url).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(dest))
      .on('close', () => res)
      .on('error', (e) => {fs.unlink(dest); err(e)})
    })
  return y
}

var process_downloaded = (dest) => {
  var p = dest.match(/_f\d\d\d\w/)[0]
  console.log(dest,'processing downloaded image')
  var r = parseInt(dest.match(/r\d+/)[0].slice(1))
  var c = parseInt(dest.match(/c\d+/)[0].slice(1))
  var record = {id: p, r: r, c: c}
  if(fs.readFileSync(dest).toString('utf8').slice(0, 5) === 'http:'){fs.unlink(dest); return {id: p, r: 0, c: 0}} // 404 error
  return record
}
```

Comment: you arent callling `res`.

Comment: `process_downloaded(path)` isn't a valid argument. Perhaps you meant `() => process_downloaded(path)`?

Comment: `.then(process_downloaded(path))` needs to be `.then(() => process_downloaded(path))` and `.on('close', () => res)` needs to be either `.on('close', res)` or `.on('close', () => res())`

Comment: Turn on warnings! Bluebird will actually tell you what's the problem

Comment: oh, calling `res` and using `() => process_downloaded(path)` fixed it, thank you so much! also I didn't know warnings were a thing, but I turned them on and they would have avoided this, you're right, thank you!

Comment: Welcome to SO! You should post your fix as an answer and accept it. :)

Answer (score 0):

There were at least two problems with this code: 
`.on('close', () => res)` will not call the `res()` function; it needs to be `.on('close', () => res())` or `.on('close', res)`.

Also, in `.then(process_downloaded(path))`: `process_downloaded(path)` is an object, but `.then()` needs a function as an argument. `.then(() => process_downloaded(path))` works properly.

To prevent errors like this in the future, `Promise.config({ warnings: true, longStackTraces: true, cancellation: true, monitoring: true })` can help; when enabled, the above mistake produces a warning, although the first one doesn't. (http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.config.html)

Also, `fs.unlink(dest)` is used twice in the code, but is not meant to be called without a callback, and produces a warning. If for some reason it took too long to complete, the file might still be there when the images are composited together afterwards. I used `fs.unlinkSync(dest)` instead. There's a performance cost but I'm not going for high performance with this.

With these changes, the code works as intended.

```
var get_image = (page_string, row, col) => {
  var url = get_url(page_string,row,col)
  var path = 'results/'+page_string+'/'+page_string.match(/f\d\d\d\w/)[0]+'_r'+pad_int(row)+'_c'+pad_int(col)+'.jpg'
  y = download(url,path)
    .then(() => process_downloaded(path))
    .then((x) => {console.log('download processed',x); return x})
  return y
}

var download = (url, dest) => {
  console.log('attempting download')
  console.log(url)
  var y = new Promise((res,err) => {
    request(url).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(dest))
      .on('close', res)
      .on('error', (e) => {fs.unlinkSync(dest); err(e)})
    })
  return y
}

var process_downloaded = (dest) => {
  var p = dest.match(/arundel_ms_263_f\d\d\d\w/)[0]
  console.log(dest,'processing downloaded image')
  var r = parseInt(dest.match(/r\d+/)[0].slice(1))
  var c = parseInt(dest.match(/c\d+/)[0].slice(1))
  var record = {id: p, r: r, c: c}
  if(fs.readFileSync(dest).toString('utf8').slice(0, 5) === 'http:'){fs.unlinkSync(dest); return {id: p, r: 0, c: 0}} // 404 error
  return record
}
```